# Api PayPal Pagamentos Automaticos

Tags: php

Existe algum tipo de api no paypal, que faça eu ao clicar num botão em meu site, enviar dinheiro da minha conta para outra conta automaticamente?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Na `API` do *PayPal* existe diversas opções, a que você procura chama-se *checkout* transparente, mas na última vez que vi (e agora que busquei para responder a pergunta) esse serviço do *PayPal* não está disponível no Brasil.

O que você pode fazer estando no Brasil é basicamente isso descrito nesse [link](https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/tutoriais/), onde há todas informações do que a `API` disponibiliza no país:

- Express Checkout Pagamento Simples – Integração Rápida
- Express Checkout Pagamento Simples – Integração Completa
- Mensagem de redirecionamento para tela de pagamento
- PayPal Sandbox: Ambiente e Criação de Contas
- Testando as APIs PayPal no Sandbox
- Credenciais de API e Certificado de API – Completo
- Guia de integração com IPN
- Configurando o conjunto de caracteres para troca de mensagens
- Express Checkout Pagamentos Recorrentes
- Express Checkout Reembolso

Entre essas opções a que mais se adequaria em se caso seria o **Express Checkout Pagamentos Recorrentes**, pois seria como uma assinatura, ou seja, seria necessário o usuário entrar no site do *PayPal* e realizar o *login* para o pagamento apenas a primeira vez, nas outros seriam os valores serão cobrados automaticamente.

Vale lembrar que não há a opção para que o dinheiro caia imediatamente em sua conta bancária (não que eu saiba, se alguém souber algo contra me corrija), pois normalmente é marcado um dia para o recebimento do seu saldo.

Caso seu pagamento tenha obrigatoriamente de ser assim sugiro buscar por *checkout* transparente e ver quais sites de pagamentos oferecem tal serviço no Brasil.